# How to display a loop inside the form?

Tags: php, html, xml, forms, loops

I want to display a query result into `value=""`

```
 for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++)
            { //loop for record count
                    ?>

    <TR>


       <TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP align="right">Invoice number or description <?php /*echo $id;*/echo $record_count;  ?></TD><!--#invPrefix#-->


                       <TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP>

                                       <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_<?php echo $record_count; ?>" Value="<?php 
                                       foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) 
                                            {

                                               echo $node_inv_no->nodeValue;
                                            }
                                       ?>" size="10">
```

but the result in textbox :

```
CI_INV000243005CI_INV000239562
```

How can I make it the first textbox `= CI_INV000243005`
and the second one `= CI_INV000239562`

?
Thanks a lot

```
**<?php
       for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++)
            { //loop for record count
                    ?>

    <TR>

       <TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP align="right">Invoice number or description <?php /*echo $id;*/echo $record_count;  ?></TD><!--#invPrefix#-->
                       <TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP>
                       <?php                       
                       foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) 
                            {   
                               $val = $node_inv_no->nodeValue;
                               echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $val . '" size="10">';
                            }
                        ?>
                                      <!-- <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_<?php //echo $record_count; ?>" Value="<?php //echo $node_inv_no->nodeValue;?>" size="10">-->

                       </TD>**
```

How can I make them display one by one not in double and top to bottom not left into right ?

I want : 
Invoice number or description 0 = CI_INV000243005
Invoice number or description 1 = CI_INV000239562

Currently it's displaying :
Invoice number or description 0 = CI_INV000243005 CI_INV000239562
Invoice number or description 1 = CI_INV000243005 CI_INV000239562

Thanks

```
<?php
$id=($_GET["clientID"]);
$max=($_GET["maxrecords"]);

echo "ID : ".$id."<br>";
echo "Max Records : ".$max."<br>";

$request_url = "http://10.21.13.12/solapp/documents/CINV/jadehttp.dll?SolApp&ClientID=$id&maxrecords=$max";
//$request_url = "http://10.21.13.12/solapp/documents/CINV/jadehttp.dll?SolApp&ClientID=42570935&maxrecords=100";
echo "Request URL : ".$request_url."<br>";


// Find only Posted status 
$doc = new DOMDocument;                                        // Create a new dom document
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;                              // Set features
$doc->formatOutput = true;                                     // Create indents on xml

$doc->Load($request_url);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]/../DocumentID';
$amount_due = $xpath->query($query2);                                 // A list of matched elements

//$query = '//Document/Status[. = "Posted"]';                       
$invoice_no = $xpath->query($query); 
$amount_due = $xpath->query($query2);                                 // A list of matched elements
$record =$invoice_no->length;                                // A list of matched elements

$invoiceArr = array();
foreach($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) {   
  $invoiceArr[] = $node_inv_no->nodeValue;                               
}

$amount_dueArr = array();
foreach ($amount_due as  $node_amount_due) 
    {
        $amount_dueArr[] = $node_amount_due->nodeValue; 
    }

?>

<?php for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++) { ?>

<TR>

<TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP align="right">
Invoice number or description <?php /*echo $id;*/echo $record_count;  ?>
</TD>

<TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP>
<?php echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $invoiceArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>'; ?>

</TD>


<td>
 <?php echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. ' Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>'; ?>
</td>


</TR>

<?php } ?>
```

I want to view pay ammount due too....but it's empty string on it,
May be I put a wrong loop ?
Any helps ?

thanks a lot

I can print out $amount_dueArr[$record_count] with : print_r($amount_dueArr[$record_count]);

but :

```
 <?php echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '
 Value="' . print_r($amount_dueArr[$record_count]) . '"
 size="10"><br>';
```

showing empty box, anyone can help ?

should be like this, I forgot one " sign

```
 <?php echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. '
 "Value="' . print_r($amount_dueArr[$record_count]) . '"
 size="10"><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Use following nested loop.

```
<?php

foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) {   
   $val = $node_inv_no->nodeValue;
   echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $val . '" size="10">';

}

?>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
$invoiceArr = array();
foreach($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) {   
  $invoiceArr[] = $node_inv_no->nodeValue;                               
}
?>

<?php for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++) { ?>

<TR>

<TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP align="right">
Invoice number or description <?php echo $record_count;  ?>
</TD>

<TD CLASS="joblog-text"colspan=2 NOWRAP>
<?php echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_' . $record_count. '" Value="' . $invoiceArr[$record_count] . '" size="10">'; ?>                                          
</TD>

</TR>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: it's displaying ok but 4 times / double,  but how can I make it top and under,not left and right and display 2 times only ??

Comment: it seems because of two loops ?

Comment: OK. I thought you are executing complete inner loop for each outer loop entry.

Comment: $invoice_no = $xpath->query($query);                                 // A list of matched elements

Comment: i can't do print_r($invoice_no)

Comment: print_r($invoice_no); ==> DOMNodeList Object ( )

Comment: @NAVEED - In your code, the **name** field for each text field, for one value of outer for loop, will be **eg_description_0**  so it will be difficult to handle. I suggest, as in my answer above, to do **eg_description_0[]**. Then the posted values can be handled properly.

Comment: I can do the same with this :

Comment: <?php
                         echo '<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_payamt_' . $record_count. ' Value="' . $amount_dueArr[$record_count] . '" size="10"><br>';                    
     ?>

Comment: empty string for $ammount_due ??

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following but it is not recommended.

```
<?php foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) { ?>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_<?php echo $record_count; ?>" Value="<?php $node_inv_no->nodeValue;?>" size="10">
<?php } ?>
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417376/408349) will be a good reference for further improvement to your code and logic handling posted data.
You can change your code to :

```
<?php foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) { ?>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_<?php echo $record_count; ?>[]" Value="<?php $node_inv_no->nodeValue;?>" size="10">
<?php } ?>
```

At the server side you will get an array of values submitted.
NOTICE:The ending `[]` at the `name` field of the `input` tag.

Comment: for($record_count=0;$record_count<$record;$record_count++)
      { //loop for record count

    foreach ($invoice_no as  $node_inv_no) { ?>
       <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="eg_description_<?php echo $record_count; ?>[]" Value="<?php $node_inv_no->nodeValue;?>" size="10">
   <?php } ?>
         <?php
   }
            ?>